# Stack all columns into two columns with categorical column in R

Tags: r, reshape

Firt of all let me create some test data:

```
dat <- data.frame(Model_A=rnorm(10, 10), Model_B=rnorm(10, 12), Data_A=rnorm(10, 11), 
Data_B=rnorm(10, 13))

# this produces the following
dat

     Model_A   Model_B    Data_A   Data_B
1  10.421684 13.201037 11.711313 13.18555
2   9.529258 11.086655 12.015787 14.13989
3   9.483633 10.697859 10.123176 15.50154
4  10.623490 11.171480  9.406222 12.56696
5  10.460739 10.925262 10.640612 11.98662
6   9.351494 10.276617 11.717629 13.00709
7  10.264206 11.587463 10.653878 13.33615
8  10.183569 13.187894 10.127552 13.87615
9   8.832003  9.739279 10.970686 13.26850
10 10.932207 11.974472 10.374939 12.11782
```

What I want to be able to do is to 'stack' all of the columns into two colums called "Model" and "Data". With the columns containing every unique combination of both the individual "Model" and "Data" columns. I would also like to create an index column that categorises the data. The dataset I would like to create is:

```
Cat             Model       Data
Model_A_Data_A  10.421684   11.711313
Model_A_Data_A  9.529258    12.015787
Model_A_Data_A  9.483633    10.123176
Model_A_Data_A  10.62349    9.406222
Model_A_Data_A  10.460739   10.640612
Model_A_Data_A  9.351494    11.717629
Model_A_Data_A  10.264206   10.653878
Model_A_Data_A  10.183569   10.127552
Model_A_Data_A  8.832003    10.970686
Model_A_Data_A  10.932207   10.374939
Model_A_Data_B  10.421684   13.18555
Model_A_Data_B  9.529258    14.13989
Model_A_Data_B  9.483633    15.50154
Model_A_Data_B  10.62349    12.56696
Model_A_Data_B  10.460739   11.98662
Model_A_Data_B  9.351494    13.00709
Model_A_Data_B  10.264206   13.33615
Model_A_Data_B  10.183569   13.87615
Model_A_Data_B  8.832003    13.2685
Model_A_Data_B  10.932207   12.11782
Model_B_Data_A  13.201037   11.711313
Model_B_Data_A  11.086655   12.015787
Model_B_Data_A  10.697859   10.123176
Model_B_Data_A  11.17148    9.406222
Model_B_Data_A  10.925262   10.640612
Model_B_Data_A  10.276617   11.717629
Model_B_Data_A  11.587463   10.653878
Model_B_Data_A  13.187894   10.127552
Model_B_Data_A  9.739279    10.970686
Model_B_Data_A  11.974472   10.374939
Model_B_Data_B  13.201037   13.18555
Model_B_Data_B  11.086655   14.13989
Model_B_Data_B  10.697859   15.50154
Model_B_Data_B  11.17148    12.56696
Model_B_Data_B  10.925262   11.98662
Model_B_Data_B  10.276617   13.00709
Model_B_Data_B  11.587463   13.33615
Model_B_Data_B  13.187894   13.87615
Model_B_Data_B  9.739279    13.2685
Model_B_Data_B  11.974472   12.11782
```

I think it must be able to be done with some of the tools in the reshape package but I can't fathom how to get the index column in there with all the unique combinations of "Model" and "Data" columns.

It's worth noting my actual dataset has 9 "Model" columans and 15 "Data" columns.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your desired output corresponds to the provided data set?

Comment: Ah I've just realised that somewhere long the way I've generated the data again to create the desired output, my mistake. I'll rectify this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also a possible soution:

```
dat <- data.frame(Model_A=rnorm(10, 10), Model_B=rnorm(10, 12), Data_A=rnorm(10, 11), 
              Data_B=rnorm(10, 13))
model.names <- grep("Model",names(dat),value=TRUE)
data.names <- grep("Data",names(dat),value=TRUE)

new.dat <- 
lapply(model.names,function(m) {
  lapply(data.names,function(d) {
    md <- cbind(dat[,m],dat[,d])
    md.name <- rep(paste0(m,"_",d),nrow(md))
    data.frame(md.name,md)
  })
 })

new.dat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(new.dat,function(l) do.call(rbind,l)))
names(new.dat) <- c("Cat","Model","Data")
```

First, it extracts the names of the models and data columns. Aferwards, using lapply twice, it creates a data frame for each combination of model and data, putting the appropriate name in the first column. The last step is to put all these data frames, which are inside a doubly nested list, into a single data frame.

Answer (score 1):

You could try by

1. Creating the combinations of "column names" (`combn(colnames...)`)
2. Remove the names from the "indx" that belong to the same type (ie. Data_A, Data_B, or Model_A, Model_B)
3. Subset the "indx" to create "indx2"
4. `split` the "indx2" by "columns" to create a list ("lst")
5. Change the names of the "lst" to identify the group ("Cat")
6. Subset the "dat" based on the "lst" names and use `unnest` from `tidyr` to rbind the list elements.

   ```
   library(tidyr)
   indx <- combn(colnames(dat),2)
   indx1 <- apply(indx, 2, function(x) length(unique(sub('_.*', '', x)))>1)
   indx2 <- indx[,indx1]
   lst <- split(indx2, col(indx2))
   names(lst) <- apply(indx2, 2, paste, collapse='_')

   res <-  unnest(lapply(lst,function(x) {
                  x1 <- dat[x] 
                  colnames(x1) <- c('Model', 'Data')
                  x1}), Cat)
   head(res,2)
   #           Cat     Model      Data
   #1 Model_A_Data_A  9.676133  9.491202
   #2 Model_A_Data_A 11.599942 10.446249
   ```

Or you could use `expand.grid` along with `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
    indx <- expand.grid(split(colnames(dat), 
                  sub("_.*", '', colnames(dat))))[2:1]
    indx1 <- transform(indx, Cat=paste(Model, Data, sep="_"))

    library(data.table)
    res1 <-  rbindlist(apply(indx1, 1, function(x) {
                x1 <- unname(x)
              data.frame(Cat=x1[3],dat[x1[1:2]])}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent solution. It's almost there but doesn't provide the categorical "Cat" column yet that I need to identify the different column combinations.

Comment: Thank you, this now works as well. I'm going to give @Stibu the answer because it works solely on the base functions.

Comment: @Catchment_Jack  I updated with expand.grid and with fewer steps.